# Method to transfer/move a Virtual farm from one host to another

Tags: virtualhost, cloud-hosting

I have a Virtual farm that consists of

- 1 DC
- 1 SQL Server
- 2 W2K8
- 7 W7 systems.

We are now looking to move that from the current solution (which is a physical host) to a cloud based solution.

- Can I just transfer the VM files?
- Is there a procedure to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what your provider has available, as the "cloud" can be implemented with Amazon's system (xen, I believe, under the hood), KVM, VMware,...

Amazon does have some service available for migrating systems to their cloud services.

Otherwise you need to work with the provider and see what's compatible. You probably won't be able to simply copy your VM's into their servers unless what you're using now is the same as what they're running.